# Excel IF/AND/OR statement

Tags: excel-formula, spreadsheet

appreciate the help:

I'm trying to write two IF/AND/OR statements to satisfy the following 
I have five columns,

1) if all of the columns are positive numbers OR some of the columns are positive numbers and some contain "NA" then I need to return "Positive".

2) if all of the columns are negative numbers OR some of the columns are negative numbers and some contain "NA" then I need to return "Negative".

My first expression to identify number 1 is working as expected:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2>=0, C2>=0,D2>=0,E2>=0,F2>=0,G2>=0,H2>=0), AND(B2="NA", C2="NA",D2="NA",E2="NA",F2="NA",G2="NA",H2="NA")), "POSITIVE", "ignore")
```

However, the same expression just changing from >=0 to <0 is not working as I would expect and is only returning "NEGATIVE" for only the rows that contain negative numbers in all the columns (i.e. combination of NAs and negative numbers are not being picked up).

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2<0, C2<0,D2<0,E2<0,F2<0,G2<0,H2<0), AND(B2="NA", C2="NA",D2="NA",E2="NA",F2="NA",G2="NA",H2="NA")), "NEGATIVE", "ignore")
```

Comment: What if they are both negative and positive?

Comment: If any row contains both positive and negative numbers I' want the output to be "ignore".

Comment: And `0` counts as positive?

Comment: Yes, 0 counts as positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=IF(AND(SUM(B2:H2) = SUMIF(B2:H2,">=0",B2:H2),COLUMNS(B2:H2) = COUNT(B2:H2) + COUNTIF(B2:H2,"NA")),"Positive",IF(AND(SUM(B2:H2) = SUMIF(B2:H2,"<0",B2:H2),COLUMNS(B2:H2) = COUNT(B2:H2) + COUNTIF(B2:H2,"NA"),COUNTIFS(B2:H2,0)=0),"Negative","Ignore"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Just wondering, the second logical AND "7 = COUNT(B125:H125)", what is this exactly doing?

Comment: Yes, I messed up.  I edited the formula to be correct.  Please use that one.  The whole is `COLUMNS(B2:H2) = COUNT(B2:H2) + COUNTIF(B2:H2,"NA"))`  It makes sure there are no other items like blanks or other words in the cells.  It says, add up the number of cells that have numbers and the number of cells that have `NA` and they should match the number of columns in the range.

Comment: Ahh, perfect. Thank you kindly.